# Псевдоклассы CSS, которые активируются при щелчке

Tags: html, css

Есть, допустим, один элемент. Каким псевдоклассом можно сделать, чтобы при клике на этот элемент, появлялся `border: 1px solid white` и оставался на этом элементе, пока я не кликнул на другой? Кажется, при помощи `active`, но не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элементы DIV могут получить фокус, если установить атрибут tabindex.

```css
.thumb-1:focus { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div class="thumb-1" tabindex="1">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно через :focus попробовать, но не думаю что этот способ подойдет везде. Тот же jQuery toggleClass(), на мой взгляд, будет надежнее.

```css
body {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

.thumb-1 {
  width: 97px;
  height: 67px;
  float: left;
}

div.thumb-1:focus {
  border: 1px solid white;
  /*Еще нужна эта строчка*/
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0px;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb-1" tabindex="0">Нажми на меня</div>
```

Comment: нет, нужно как то без Jquery обойтись

Comment: Тогда попробуйте [Фокус](http://htmlbook.ru/css/focus)

Comment: .thumb-1{
        width: 97px;
        height: 67px;
        float: left;
    }
    .thumb-1:focus{
        border:1px solid white;
    } никакого результата не дало

Comment: Нужно к .thumb-1 добавить  tabindex="0". И в .thumb-1:focus переписать outline, который по дефолту outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;.  Я добавил код вверхнем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Один из возможных способов - использовать псевдокласс target.

```css
#qwe:target {
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="qwe">Вот ваш элемент, щёлкните <a href="#qwe">сюда</a></div>
```